# Alternative way to restrict an employee to work on multiple jobs

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, scheduling

Suppose I have a set of employee $E$ and set of jobs $J$ in a given time horizon $T$. I would like to make sure that no employee works on multiple jobs where each job $e\in E$ takes a certain amount of time presented as $\delta_e$.

Let $X_{ejt}$ be a binary variables stating if employee $e$ starts working on job $j$ at time $t$. Then, I can write;

$ M(X_{ejt}-1) \geq \sum_{i \in J \setminus \{ j\}} \sum_{t^* : t \leq t^*  < t + \delta_j}  X_{eit^*}, \quad \forall e \in E, j \in J, t \in T$

where the constraint ensures that employee $e$ cannot work on another job until their current job is completed.

My question is that if there is a better way to accomplish this with a more effective constraint without leaning on a big-M constraint. When I say efficient, I mean it should work better during the B$\&$B process.

Comment: Does $X_{ejt}=1$ mean employee $e$ is working on job $j$ at time $t$ or that $e$ *begins* job $j$ at time $t?$ If the former, your constraint is incorrect, because it blocks $j$ from starting a new job until $\delta_e$ time units after the *current* time rather than after the time $e$ started $j.$ Also, the summation on the right would need to exclude $i=j.$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works better is an empirical question. Only experimentation will tell.

First, note that your "big M" may in fact not be all that big. $M=\vert J \vert-1$ is sufficiently large to do the job.

That said, one way to avoid $M$ involves adding new variables $Y_{ejt}\ge 0$ and more constraints. It makes the model larger (generally not desirable) but may or may not make the bounds tighter. The additional constraints are $$Y_{ejt} \ge \sum_{\tau=t-\delta_j + 1}^t X_{ej\tau}\quad \forall e,j,t$$ (with suitable adjustments to the lower limit of summation to skip negative times) and $$\sum_{j\in J}Y_{ejt} \le 1\quad \forall e,t.$$ The first new constraint forces $Y_{ejt} \ge 1$ if $e$ starts $j$ before time $t$ but close enough that $j$ would still be in progress at time $t.$ In other words, you will get $Y_{ejt}=1$ if $e$ is doing $j$ at $t.$ The second constraint says that any employee at any time can be doing at most one job.

Answer (score 0):

Choose M as an upper bound, $U$ of number jobs an employee $e$ can be assigned over time horizon $T$, then
$\sum_{j \in \{J-j\}}\sum_{t\le t^* \le t+\delta_j}x_{e,j,t^*} \le U(1-x_{e,j,t}) \ \ \forall e \in E \ \ \forall j \in J$

If you want to avoid use of U or M then

$\sum_j x_{e,j,t} \le 1 \ \ \forall t \ \ \forall e $ (1)

$\delta_j x_{e,j,t} \le \sum_{\tau = t}^{t+\delta_j-1}(x_{e,j,\tau}) + C \le \delta_j \ \ \forall C \in \{0,1,...\delta_j-1 \} \ \ \forall t \ \ \forall e \ \ \forall j$ (2)

OR: Alternate to cons (2)

$\delta_jx_{e,j,t-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{t-1} x_{e,j,k} \le \delta_j x_{e,j,t} $ (3)

$\sum_{k=1}^{t-1}x_{e,j,k} - \delta_jx_{e,j,t-1} \le \delta_j (1-x_{e,j,t}) $ (4)

$\forall t \in \{2,...T\} \ \ \forall j \ \ \forall e $

Comment: I think your last constraint is incorrect.

Comment: yes realized its like  a moving thing, t,t+1,t+2.. so added that $ \delta_t$

Comment: I still don't understand your last constraint. Suppose that $x_{ejt}=1.$ Then for every $\delta_t$ in the correct range, you have $\delta_j \le 1 + \delta_t \le \delta_j ,$ which means $ 1 + \delta_t = \delta_j$ for a variety of values of $\delta_t,$ which can't be true.

Comment: I get $\delta_t$ with $t$ as index was creating confusion. Its like when $x_ejt =1$ for a time $t$ then all $x$s through $t+\delta_j$ are forced to be 1, summing upto $\delta_j$. So to avoid the model to continue to make time slots beyond duration as time $t$ loops on the lhs, $C$ acts as a counter.

Comment: Suppose employ $e$ starts job $j,$ which has duration 2 time units $(\delta_j=2),$ at time $t$ $(x_{ejt}=1).$ Your revised last constraint seems to say $2\cdot 1 = x_{e,j,t}+x_{e,j,t+1}+x_{e,j,t+2}+C=2$ for $C\in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace.$ That cannot hold for both $C=0$ and $C=1.$ Also, the middle expression only looks at $x_{e,j,\cdot},$ indicators for when $e$ might start $j$. The constraint needs to prevent $e$ from starting other jobs $j^\prime \neq j$ while $e$ is working on $j.$

Comment: I have corrected the upper boundary of summation. So my thinking is $2 \le x_{ejt}+x_{ejt+1} +0 \le 2$ then as $t$ loops, $2 \le x_{ejt+1}+x_{ejt+2} +1 \le 2$. There it will prevent $x_{ejt+2}=0$ as $x_{ejt+1}=1$. As to prevent other jobs being taken first constraint ensures that for $e$ for time $t$, total jobs is 1. As you mentioned just because OP is trying an alternate to bigM, otherwise these are not very sure shot constraints.

Comment: Hello Prof @prubin, hope the alternate set of constraints are correct and tighter.

Comment: Sorry, but no. Suppose $\delta_1 = \delta_2 = 2$ and $x_{1,1,1}=1.$ So far, this should be valid, but it violates (2) for $e=j=t=1$ and $C=0$ $(2 \le 1 + 0 \le 2).$ It also violates (3) when $t=2$ $(2 - 1 \le 0).$ Now suppose you fix that. I don't see anything preventing $x_{1,1,1}=1=x_{1,2,2},$ even though this would have employee 1 doing two projects at time 2.